# Why forms authentication forgotten (reset) after hosting change

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, web-hosting

I have a .NET 4 MVC application. After I moved to another hosting, all authenticated users "forget" their credentials, so all had to log in again.

Domain name remains unchanged, validation and decryption keys are specified in web.config explicitly. Does encryption method use some machine-specific keys?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the validation and decryption keys are specified in web.config explicitly, it's possible for other [machinekey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) defaults (e.g. encryption and validation algorithms) to be inherited from the .Net Framework machine.config or web.config for the host. You should ensure that all possible values in the machinekey and forms authentication settings sections are explicitly set in your web.config.

You didn't say if it's shared hosting with subdomains, but I wonder if your host perhaps prevent people from using the default cookie name .ASPXAuth since that may conflict with others on the host.

Comment: I explicitly set both <authentication> and <machineKey> elements in my web.config.

Comment: Also, there is www. subdomain, and I set '<authentication mode="Forms">
 <forms .... domain=".mydomain.com" />' to enable authentication cookie on all subdomains.

Comment: OK, looks like this may not be the problem. Just to be sure though, you might want to edit the question to post the relevant web.config sections (with the keys obfuscated).

Answer (score 0):

A potential cause is that one of the hosters is running without [the MS11-100 patch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS11-100).  You should confirm with the hosters that they are staying up-to-date via Windows Update.